# Disable .htaccess rules on certain folders

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using these lines of codes to remove any .html from all the links on my own website, which is plain HTML and CSS without a CMS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

This works all fine but it also affects all the subfolders of my domain including my development folders. This causes some errors with Wordpress websites for example.

Is there a way to remove the .html from files that are only in the root of my server or to disable this rewrite rule on specific folders?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to skip your rewrite rule in a folder called `blog/`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!blog/)([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually answered my own question on purpose by placing the .htaccess file in the specific folder but only without the code posted in my question. It seems to work fine that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -indexes
DirectoryIndex admin.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>
```

hmm i'm using a htaccess code for my application. and it's work :D